# How to download files with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I wonder what techniques would you use when, say a page contains links to 6 videos, 300Mb each and you want to download them all. Should I write my custom downloader?

I'm used to use MediaPipeline but it utilizes the framework scheduler which has the following issues:

1. You never know which file is currently being downloaded
2. You have no idea on download progress/state until it fails
3. Strange timeout behaviour:
   a) Looks like timeout is applied to the whole request download operation, not only to pauses in download. So, say, having a timeout of 5min I will never be able to download a file which takes 6 min to download. b) If you make 5 concurrent long requests and one of them is taking too long, you will get all of them (not complete yet) timed out. You have to limit the number of concurrent requests by 1 in settings (which will affect the whole spider).

Comment: Why do you need progress/state reports? I'm pretty sure media pipeline does log those events and if the logs are not visible maybe lower the logger level to INFO (might be set to WARNING).

Comment: Because I've repeateadly encountered situation when half files fail (when having a few large files in a queue) with timout/start retrying and I can't even say if it because of one file or few files or a bug in framework. And it would be a nightmare if happened on customers site. As a workaround I set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1 and it seems to be the cure, at least one time everything finished fine

Comment: I always use DEBUG level and it reports nothing. I add my own messages in the pipeline, but when I yield 6 items a row I only see they all started immediately, then finished one-by-one. I don't even an item is queued/actually requested

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Youtube downloader](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md) after having retrieve links to the videos.

Youtube downloader will try to continue if video has not finished downloading. You can also force it to continue. Write a wrapper around it for concurrency if it takes long for single downloads.

Disclaimer: I am not in anyway affiliated with the maintainers of this package.

Comment: I use it, but when it is tricky to extract an url from a page. Y-dl itself uses external downloaders, are you sure it makes sense to use it when having a direct video url?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to do that.